# How to disable elements with css

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

The following code limits the amount of selections to 3, and provides an alert to say that no more can be selected.

Instead of this I would like the other options to be disabled and greyed out with CSS.  I thought a simple adding of a class called .disabled with a css style of opacity of 0.2 would do the trick.

I tried using this `$('ul.image_picker_selector li').attr('class', 'disabled');` but it breaks the rest of my code and adds the class to all options not just the ones that arent selected.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
       $(document).on('mousedown', 'ul.image_picker_selector li', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();

        // get the number of items already selected:
        var ctSelected = $(this).siblings('.selected').length;

        if (ctSelected === 3) {
            alert('You have already selected 3 items!' + ('\n') + 'You can undo a selection.');
        } else {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        }
    });
    })
        </script>

    <ul class="thumbnails image_picker_selector">
    <li class="selected">
    <div class="thumbnail selected">
    <img class="image_picker_image" src="http://www.style-card.co.uk/id/assets/img/signup/Q1-1.jpg">
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class=""><div class="thumbnail selected">
    <img class="image_picker_image" src="http://www.style-card.co.uk/id/assets/img/signup/Q1-2.jpg">
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <img class="image_picker_image" src="http://www.style-card.co.uk/id/assets/img/signup/Q1-3.jpg">
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <img class="image_picker_image" src="http://www.style-card.co.uk/id/assets/img/signup/Q1-4.jpg">
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <img class="image_picker_image" src="http://www.style-card.co.uk/id/assets/img/signup/Q1-5.jpg">
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <img class="image_picker_image" src="http://www.style-card.co.uk/id/assets/img/signup/Q1-6.jpg">
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I need the options that arent selected to have a css class added to them - this works $('li').not('.selected').css('opacity', '0.2');

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. And your title is wrong. You can't disabled and element via CSS. Only change it's appearence (Styling). To disabled and therefore change and element in the DOM tree you might use javascript. And, why use document to bind your function? And your toggleClass('selected') probably is not doing what you want. Wouldn't you check the status first? Try and rephrase your question to get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector should work :

```
$('ul.image_picker_selector li:not(.selected)').addClass('disabled');
```

Also, using `addClass` is not breaking your other CSS and can be easy reverted with `removeClass` unlike (if i am not mistaken) using `attr` to change class.

You can even go deeper and use `toggleClass`.

Comment: This works great, but what about with multiple ul lists with that class?  It adds that class to the other ones on that page also?

Comment: On top of that, when I unselect a li, I would like the class to be removed...any ideas?

Comment: This removes the class -     if (ctSelected < 3) {
$('ul.image_picker_selector li:not(.selected)').removeClass('disabled');
    }

Comment: Any idea on how to only apply this to the ul in question and not other uls on the page with that class (.image_picker_selector)?

Comment: For the removeClass, just do `$('.disabled').removeClass('disabled')`. For the "ul in question" i would do `$(this).closest('.image_picker_selector').find('li:not(.selected)')`. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ? [Example on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yUSnw/)

i've added this:

```
   if (ctSelected === 2) {
            $('ul.image_picker_selector li').not('.selected').addClass('disabled')
        }
```